# ASP.Net master page scrollbar question

Tags: asp.net, css

Like happens to all of us sometimes, I inherited some crappy code I have to fix.

We need to center our pages on widescreen machines, so we have a master page layout div like so:

```
.MasterLayout
{
width:1100px;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-550px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

I removed most of the detailed attributes for readability here, but here's how the table for the master page is laid out:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 100%" align="center" colspan="2">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="height: 20px; background-color: #333;">
   <asp:SiteMapPath/>
  </td>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 86px; height: 650px; background-color: #B5C7DE; margin: 6px;" valign="top">
   <asp:Menu />
   <asp:SiteMapDataSource />
  </td>
  <td style="background-color:#ffffff; margin:5px; width:1000px;" valign="top">
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When resizing the browser window, the horizontal scrollbar only reaches as far as the left edge of the `<asp:contentplaceholder/>` control, and the `<asp:menu/>` that's in the 86px wide `<td>` is hidden. How can I fix this problem? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 2):

Try centering the .MasterLayout using [margin: 0px auto](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html) instead of the [negative margin method](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center2.html).

While you're updating the code, you might also consider using divs instead of tables for page layout.

Comment: For that solution, he also needs to remove the position:absolute; and left:50%; declarations as well

Answer (score 0):

Put contentPlaceholder in a div and control the overflow with css overflow property of that div. I suggest you to use width of main block like #masterlayout, #sidebar in %.